# PHP lat/lon in polygon function that accommodates crossing hemispheres

Tags: php, latitude-longitude, point-in-polygon

I currently use the function below to determine if a lat/lon is inside a polygon on earth.

```
public function inPolygon($lat, $lon, $polylat, $polylon) {
    $j=count($polylat)-1;
    $oddNodes=false;
    for($i=0;$i<count($polylat);$i++){
        if($polylat[$i]<$lat && $polylat[$j]>=$lat || $polylat[$j]<$lat && $polylat[$i]>=$lat){
            if($polylon[$i]+($lat-$polylat[$i])/($polylat[$j]-$polylat[$i])*($polylon[$j]-$polylon[$i])<$lon){
                $oddNodes=!$oddNodes;
            }
        }
        $j=$i;
    }
    return $oddNodes;
}
```

The problem is I now have a polygon on earth that stretches from latitude -176.57 to 173.73 then back into the western hemisphere again. The function I currently use obviously works only if the lat/lon are all in the same hemisphere.

How can I fix this function to accommodate the crossing of hemispheres?

Comment: Did you check it for your particular use-case? You do not use absolute values, math should be correct both for negative and positive namespace. Check sample here: http://assemblysys.com/php-point-in-polygon-algorithm/